# Tenants created in IS server are not able to login to the publisher portal of the API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have done HA setup of APIM 3.2 with IS 5.10 and using IS as a keymanager.

Now the issue with publisher and devportal portal login. I have created a tenant from IS carbon portal and I am able to login to IS carbon portal with newly created tenant admin credentials but when I try to login to publisher or devportal using same tenant admin credentials it says "Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again.".

what could be the reason? any configuration changes required to sync tenants created under IS portal to APIM?

Comment: Can you try adding the tenant domain at the end of the username with @ symbol? Eg: If the tenant name is ‘test.com’ and admin name is bob provide the username as bob@test.com

Comment: yes, I am trying to login adding tenant domain along with username. It is failing.

Comment: I hope you have configured the databases properly with the key manager and APIM. If that is fine can you try creating the same tenant with the same admin credentials in the APIM side (Only the tenant creation is needed. Others will sync automatically)? AFAIK there was an error in one of the tenant mgt event listeners and this should have been fixed by now.

Comment: IDM Deployment.toml: looks like this ....[database.identity_db]: WSO2AM_QA_DB" [database.shared_db]:WSO2_QA_SHARED_DB"[database.user] : WSO2_QA_SHARED_DB"

APIM Deployment: Looks like this ....[database.apim_db]:WSO2AM_QA_DB, [database.shared_db]:WSO2_QA_SHARED_DB

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding the configs in [1] and try. If that does not work try creating the same tenant in the APIM side? Afaik there was some missing config information in the docs.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/docs-apim/pull/6176/files

Comment: Hi Sominda, thanks for your quick replies. when i login to APIM carbon console I see that tenant which I have created from carbon portal already exists in apim carbon portal. but when I tried to login to to APIM carbon portal with tenant admin credentials it was throwing same error as publisher/devportal "Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again." Please advise how to proceed here. hope my DB configurations shared above are fine.

Comment: I verified DB entries in WSO2_SHARED_DB. "um_user" table has no entries it is empty. Cross verified "um_user" table entries from a working environment and it has tenantadmin and other users records. What could be the reason here in our case for "um_user" table not being updated with the user details.

Comment: Maybe the databases are not pointing to the same DBs. Check the `UM_USER` tablee in IS as well.
Can you update the issue with the latest findings? Also, add the userstore-related toml configs? (make sure to mask sensitive info).

Comment: Both IS [database.user] and APIM [database.shared_db] are poinitng to same WSO2_QA_SHARED_DB.

Comment: **[user_store.properties]**
TenantManager="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager"
ConnectionURL= "ldap://<ldap-node1-ip>:port ldap://<ldap-node2-ip>:port"
ConnectionName= "cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com"
UserSearchBase= "ou=Users,dc=test,dc=com"
GroupSearchBase= "ou=Groups,dc=test,dc=com"
ConnectionPassword= "xxxxx"
AnonymousBind= "false"
WriteGroups= "true"
UserEntryObjectClass= "identityPerson"
UserNameAttribute= "uid"
UserNameSearchFilter= "(\u0026amp;(objectClass\u003dperson)(uid\u003d?))"
UserNameListFilter= "(objectClass=person)"
DisplayNameAttribute= ""

Comment: **continuation of user_store.properties**

GroupEntryObjectClass= "groupOfNames"
GroupNameAttribute= "cn"
GroupNameSearchFilter= "(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))"
GroupNameListFilter= "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
MembershipAttribute= "member"
BackLinksEnabled= "false"
SCIMEnabled= "true"
IsBulkImportSupported= "true"
UsernameJavaRegEx = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-|//]{3,30}$"
RolenameJavaRegEx = "[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-|//]{3,30}$"

Comment: PasswordHashMethod= "PLAIN_TEXT"
ConnectionPoolingEnabled= "false"
LDAPConnectionTimeout= "5000"
ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin= "true"
EmptyRolesAllowed= "true"
kdcEnabled= "false"
defaultRealmName= "TEST.COM"
StartTLSEnabled= "false"
UserRolesCacheEnabled= "true"
ConnectionRetryDelay= "2m"
MaxUserNameListLength="100"
MaxRoleNameListLength="100"

Comment: Hi Sominda, Any inputs to resolve my issue?